# Losing hover when animating with jQuery (without moving mouse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate, mouse

I have this row of thumbnails that I am animating with jQuery.
Each of these thumbnails has a hover and active class.

They work fine but when I animate the list, the new thumbnail under the mousecursor does not apply the hover? I have to move the mouse a little bit after each click?

It's kinda difficult to exaplain.. I have made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nZGYA/
When you start clicking after thumb 3 without moving the mouse you see what I mean...

It works fine in FireFox, NOT Safari, Chrome, IE etc.
Is there something I can do about this?

For reference here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container { position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 140px; height: 460px; float: left; margin-right: 100px; background: silver;  }            
    ul { position: absolute; top: 10; list-style: none; margin: 10px; padding: 0; }
    li { margin-bottom: 10px; width: 120px; height: 80px; background: gray; }
    #list-2 li a { display: block; width: 120px; height: 80px; outline: none; }
    #list-2 li a:hover { background: teal; }
    #list-2 li a.active { background: navy; }
</style>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var idx_2 = 0;
    $('#list-2 li a')
    .click(function() {
        $('#list-2 > li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');         
        var id =  $('#list-2 li a.active').data('index') - 2;
        idy = Math.max(0, id * 90);
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({ 'top' : -idy + 'px' });
        return false;
    })
    .each(function() {
        $(this).data('index', idx_2);
        ++idx_2;
    });
});

<div class="container">
    <ul id="list-2">
        <li><a class="active" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I have objects that move and I want to be able to detect hover... even if the mouse doesn't move but an object moves to become underneath it.

Answer (score 3):

I only worked on the top list but I think I got it all working. let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Here is the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/colemande/c2u5b/)

```
var idx = 0;
$('#list-1 li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
}).click

(function() {
    var currentindex = $('.active').index();
    var selectedindex = $(this).index();
    var nexthoverindex = selectedindex + (selectedindex - currentindex);


//counter for starting on index 1
if(currentindex === 1 && selectedindex > 2){
    nexthoverindex = nexthoverindex - 1;
}

//counter for starting on index 0
if(currentindex === 0 && selectedindex > 2){
    nexthoverindex = nexthoverindex - 2;
}

//make sure the selection never goes below 0
if(nexthoverindex < 0){
    nexthoverindex = 0;
}

$('#list-1 > li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
var id = $('#list-1 li.active').data('index') - 2; // take scroll param and subtract 2 to keep selected image in the middle
idy = Math.max(0, id * 90);
$(this).parent().animate({
    'top': -idy + 'px'
},200, function(){           
    $('.hover').removeClass('hover');
    if(currentindex > 2 || selectedindex > 2){
    $('#list-1 > li').eq(nexthoverindex).addClass('hover');
    }
});
return false;
}).css('cursor', 'pointer').each(function() {
    $(this).data('index', idx);
    ++idx;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution that works in Chrome and IE (haven't tested in Safari). Basically I trigger the mouseover() event of the element under the mouse in the animate() callback event if the thumbnails have moved. The solution is only implemented for list-1.

```
// list 1
var idx = 0;
$('#list-1 li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
}).click(function() {
    $('#list-1 > li').removeClass('active');
    var $active = $(this);
    $active.addClass('active');
    var id = $('#list-1 li.active').data('index') - 2; // take scroll param and subtract 2 to keep selected image in the middle

    var moveAmount = 90;
    idy = Math.max(0, id * moveAmount);
    var oldPos = $active.parent().position().top;

    $active.parent().animate({
        'top': -idy + 'px'
    }, function(){

        var newPos = $(this).position().top;

        // Check if we moved
        if(oldPos - newPos != 0)
        {
            var movement = (oldPos - newPos) / moveAmount;
            $($(this).children()[$active.index() + movement])
                .trigger("mouseover");

        }

    });
    return false;
}).css('cursor', 'pointer').each(function() {
    $(this).data('index', idx);
    ++idx;
});
```

And here's the link to my fork in jsfiddle if you wan't to test it out over there - http://jsfiddle.net/jimmysv/3tzAt/15/

Comment: That is great! It works in Safari as wel :-) Thank you so much for your work. Now I just hope it's not to difficult to implement in jcarousel.. because my exmple was just the basic idea. Cheers Jimmy!

Comment: mmm, I found a bug. when clicking +2 or -2 thumbs the hover is not correct. Oh well, thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that several hours ago but didn't notice that jsFiddle changed the link. I have now updated my answer with a link to the correct version.

Comment: It's also a little buggy still if you click and move your mouse off the box before animation is over. Maybe a simple before and after mouse positioning check in relation to the window would handle that?

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution. Don't really know how else it could be done on top of my head.