# CSS hover animation not playing when item slid under mouse in webkit

Tags: html, css, hover

Im look as much as possible to avoid having to use a JS solution for this. But if that is my only option to get this working then ill bite the bullet.

I have a slide out nav section that has a toggle button in it.. this nav section covers a topbar that has a corresponding toggle button in it..

they both have hover animations using CSS3 animations applied to the `:hover` attribute. My issue occurs because both toggle buttons align with one another.. so when the nav is opened and closed you do not need to move your cursor.. because of this the `:hover` event doesnt appear to be getting triggered on the new element that is under the cursor until you move your mouse..

However, on Firefox they do appear to get triggered

I have had a look at people having issues with this to do with jQuery hover events not firing: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925550/losing-hover-when-animating-with-jquery-without-moving-mouse)

If anyone knows of a css or html way to do this i would be very greatful. My fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2fa/1/

EDIT:to test this please click on the open/close menu button (top left hamburger) then without moving your mouse click the button again to close the nav.. you shoul only experience the `:hover` event when you click or move your mouse

EDIT:this seems to definitely be occurring on OSX Chrome, OSX Safari (havent got a PC to test with)

Comment: Seems to be working in the fiddle, but I see some JS. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @shaan singh, have edited with a use case, please dont move your mouse when you are opening and closing (you should only see the animation on click), otherwise please provide browser and os details :) also the desire for no JS is more for to keep things lightweight than anything..